# angular-materialize element.leanModal is not a function

Tags: angularjs, materialize

I'm using angular materialize from https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize

I have the following issue, when I call a modal, it tells me that `element.leanModal is not a function` on the console, and instead, it tries to reload the page.

Everything is included and in order:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/angular-materialize.js"></script>
        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/wallCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/directives/nicescroll.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
```

Here is the trigger for the modal `#newpost`:

```
...
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
  <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#newpost" modal>New Post</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

And here is the modal snippet:

```
<div id="newpost" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4>New Post</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#!" class="modal-action waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Post</a>
                <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

It's included as a dependency on my `app.js` file:

```
angular
  .module('leseaApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.materialize'
  ])
```

Everything is done right according to the documentation, yet I have that error. Any idea what is possibly going wrong? It's been a couple of hours I have tried everything: reinstalling stuff via bower and yeoman, downgrading to older versions, but nothing works so far. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? I encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `jQuery`needs to be loaded before Angular, so that Angular knows it doesn't have to use jQuerylite. jQuerylite would work, but MaterializeCSS has certain modules that completely depend on jQuery.

Comment: Not true, I still got the error even if my jQuery library comes first.
See [screenshot](http://image.prntscr.com/image/e8c8fa6303984afbb59522ffaec9fde7.png)